# How to set the default value of a TRxDBLookupCombo control?

Tags: delphi

Hi all

As the title say. What I want is to make a value as the default value when  click a Add button
in the form, the value will be used as a propertity of a document which  will be added.
(Yes, this is used in a document management app, one field in the doc will be determined by user via choosing a value in combo, I wanna give user their most possible choice. But now,the default value of combo is empty.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign the value you want to the field in the dataset which the lookup combobox is attached. The combobox then seek this value in the lookup dataset (the key value) ant show the field value (list value)